# Don't select from second dropdownlist from already selected item in the first dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two dropdownlist with same set of questions.
I have to "NOT to show" the selected item from the 1st dropdown and vice versa. If I selected question 1 from the 1st dropdown it will not be available on the 2nd.

Below is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ChallengeQuestion1, (SelectList)ViewBag.ChallengeQuestions, "-- Challenge Question 1 --", new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ChallengeQuestion1)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ChallengeAnswer1, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Answer" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ChallengeAnswer1)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ChallengeQuestion2, (SelectList)ViewBag.ChallengeQuestions, "-- Challenge Question 2 --", new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ChallengeQuestion2)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ChallengeAnswer2, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Answer" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ChallengeAnswer2)
```

Comment: This is my set of questions
   public IEnumerable<DropDownListItem> GetChallengeQuestions()
        {
            var questions = new List<DropDownListItem>
            {
                new DropDownListItem { Name = "question1?" },
                new DropDownListItem { Name = "question2?" },
               
              

            return questions;
        }

Comment: You need to use javascript to hide or disable the option in the other `<select>` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stephen already told you have to do it on client side.

```
var $dropdown1 = $("select[name='dropdown1']");
var $dropdown2 = $("select[name='dropdown2']");

$dropdown1.change(function() {
    var selectedItem = $(this).val();        
    $("select[name='dropdown2'] > option[value=" +selectedItem +"]").attr('disabled', true)
    .siblings().removeAttr('disabled'); 
});
```

Comment: You do not want to remove the option - just hide or disable it (the user might change their mind and select another option) and the code needs to show or enable any hidden or disabled options.

Comment: Thank @neel for your answer,disabling or hiding is OK.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove second dropdown option when first dropdown option is seleted.
you can do this by writing javascript change event of first dropdown and remove first selected option from second dropdown.

```
$("select[name='ChallengeQuestion1']").change(function() {
    var selectedItem = $(this).val();        
    $("select[name='ChallengeQuestion2'] > option[value=" +selectedItem +"]").remove();  
});
```